# The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, sha1

I am trying to calculate sha1 hash for some of the files from location %system%\drivers\ using C#. I know files are at the exact location but when i use

```
FILE.Exists("c:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\1394ohci.sys")
```

it always retuns false.

```
C:\Users\administrator>dir c:\Windows\System32\drivers\1394ohci.sys
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5A4F-1E60

 Directory of c:\Windows\System32\drivers

11/21/2010  08:53 AM           229,888 1394ohci.sys
               1 File(s)        229,888 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  19,521,245,184 bytes free


C:\Users\administrator>fciv -sha1 c:\Windows\system32\drivers\1394ohci.sys
//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
c:\windows\system32\drivers\1394ohci.sys\*
        Error msg  : The system cannot find the path specified.
        Error code : 3
```

I even tried fciv.exe on the file and it also generate the same output. I tried running the command as administratror but it did not help.

I did lot of web search but nothing worked. Please help and let me know how to fix this issue.

Appreciate your help.
Thank you,

Comment: Does the running user have access permissions to 1394ohci.sys?

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit version of Windows? If so, file system redirection is kicking in. This is a 32-bit application, but you're asking it to look in a 64-bit directory. It's getting automagically redirected to `SysWOW64`, which probably doesn't contain `1394ohci.sys`.

Comment: First of all your comment on nmjohn's answer belongs as a question comment. Second, compile your application as a 32 bit application.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your problem correctly then you need to look at [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The %windir%\System32 directory is `reserved` for 64-bit applications.
>   Most DLL file names were not changed when 64-bit versions of the DLLs
>   were created, **so 32-bit versions of the DLLs are stored in a
>   different directory**. `WOW64` hides this difference using a file
>   system redirector.
>
> In most cases, **whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access
>   %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64**.
>   Access to %windir%\lastgood\system32 is redirected to
>   %windir%\lastgood\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\regedit.exe is
>   redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe.

Also there is small sample at the bottom of page if you can try that one

```
string system32Directory = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%"), "system32");
if(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
// For 32-bit processes on 64-bit systems, %windir%\system32 folder
// can only be accessed by specifying %windir%\sysnative folder.
system32Directory = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%"), "sysnative");
}
```

Comment: Why does it not tell us the path of the file that couldn't be found? Makes it very frustrating to debug.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is the file system redirector at work. The workaround is to replace **system32** with **sysnative** in the filepath.

This was driving me bonkers too, and it took too much work to find the simple workaround. I kept landing on pages with advanced scripting and complicated, obscure tangentially-related solutions. So I thought I'd share the "easy mode".

Answer (score 0):

Run your program in Administrator Mode.

Comment: hi Codey Gray,Yes I am using 64 bit version of windows and yes SysWOW64 doesnt contain 1394ohci.sys file. How do i fix it? How can i stop redirection from code?

Answer (score -1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx:

> The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file.